# Bad JWT signature trying to use the Google Drive API

Tags: api, powershell, google-drive-api, oauth2-playground

I've seen articles about manipulating files with Google Drive using a personal OAuth2 token in PowerShell, but not with domain-wide privileges.

From what I understand, the workflow goes like this:

1. Create the header, base64 encode
2. Create the claim, base64 encode
3. Combine the header and claim, then sign it with RSA256 and the private key provided by Google

I'm having issues with step 3. Please see the below code:

```
$firstdate = Get-Date -Year 1970 -Month 1 -Day 1 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0
$endtime = (New-TimeSpan -Start $firstdate -End (Get-Date).AddMinutes(30).ToUniversalTime()).TotalSeconds
$issuetime = (New-TimeSpan -Start $firstdate -End (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).TotalSeconds
$jsonfile = Get-Content 'secret_file.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

$headerhash = [ordered]@{
    'alg' = 'RS256'
    'typ' = 'JWT'
}
$headerjson = $headerhash | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$encodedheader = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($headerjson))

$claimhash = [ordered]@{
    'iss' = $jsonfile.client_email
    'scope' = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    'aud' = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
    'exp' = [math]::Round($endtime,0)
    'iat' = [math]::Round($issuetime,0)
}
$claimjson = $claimhash | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$encodedclaim = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($claimjson))

#$sha = [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::Create()
#$sha.Key = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.Getbytes($jsonfile.private_key)
#$sha.FromXmlString($sha.ToXmlString($jsonfile.private_key))
#$signature = $sha.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$encodedheader.$encodedclaim"))
#$signature = $sha.SignData([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$encodedheader.$encodedclaim"),[System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig]::MapNameToOID('RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN'))
#$encodedsignature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
#$formatter = [System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter]::new($sha)
#$formatter.SetKey($sha)
#$formatter.CreateSignature([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$encodedheader.$encodedclaim"))

$jws = "$encodedheader.$encodedclaim"
$encodedjws = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($jws)

$rsa = [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::Create()
# This is the key -- need to convert PEM to proper format
$rsa.FromXmlString($rsa.ToXmlString($jsonfile.private_key))
$sha256OID = [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig]::MapNameToOID("SHA256")
$signature = $rsa.SignData($encodedjws,$sha256OID)
$encodedsignature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

$jwt = "$encodedheader.$encodedclaim.$encodedsignature"

$requestUri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
$method = 'POST'
$body = [ordered]@{
    'grant_type' = 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'
    'assertion' = $jwt
}
Invoke-webrequest -Uri $requestUri -Method $method -Body $body -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

The errors I'm getting are indicating a bad JWT signature. The secret key Google is providing is in PEM format, but I'm having issues translating it into something Powershell can understand.

Comment: I think this is an "Ace" question for Powershell and was wondering whether you had figured it out in the end..? I fiddled around with very similar code to try and implement Google's OAuth 2.0 using HTTP/REST here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Can't use UrlEncode, so clean instead

$encodedheader = $encodedheader.Split('=')[0]
$encodedheader = $encodedheader.Replace('+', '-')
$encodedheader = $encodedheader.Replace('/', '_')

Same for $encodedclaim and $encodedsignature

Comment: How did you know if this call returns the private key correctly..?

$rsa.FromXmlString($rsa.ToXmlString($jsonfile.private_key));

Certainly get an impressive $encodedsignature back, although it seems a bit short..!

How would you know if it was actually correct..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue for a while until I came across using the OWIN libraries to do it.

Here's the link to my Get-GSToken function that's part of my PSGSuite module. You can tear this apart if you'd like to do what you need (the purpose of that function is to grab a token), but you'll need the `nuget` folder as well in order for it to work (OWIN libraries are contained in there):

https://github.com/nferrell/PSGSuite/blob/master/Public/Get-GSToken.ps1

Feel free to grab the entire module for samples! I've wrapped almost all of the Google API calls into Powershell functions in there, all leveraging `Get-GSToken` to first grab a token at the scope the function needs.

Something to note: this leverages a service account and a P12 key file, not the clientsecrets.json file key type. I'm not sure how to build a working JWT with pure Powershell using the JSON file, but the P12 + OWIN libraries work amazingly well for it.

Comment: Looks great, @nferrell, thanks. The only thing you're using those OWIN libraries for in that function is to do the base64 encoding. I'm not sure where the rest of the module uses that, but you can just as easily use [System.Convert]::ToBase64String() for that. I think we can consider this solved, though.

Comment: The OWIN libraries specifically handle *WebSafe/URLSafe* Base64 encoding, which there's no true built-in library for (`$encoder = New-Object Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder.Base64UrlTextEncoder`)... I attempted the workaround via char replacement and accounting for padding, but it never worked in the months that I was working on it. I'm totally fine with using an external library personally if I know it works quick and easy